# I want to include swiper in my Angular4 App

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, swiper.js

I want to include swiper (http://idangero.us/swiper/) in my Angular4 App, But it depends on jquery.
what should i do?

Comment: There is a 'get started' link right on the page you linked to...? http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/

Comment: First off read the SO rules on asking questions and after that I'd try your preferred search engine

Answer (score 2):

this script doesn't depends on jquery...
Just add this 2 lines :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/swiper.min.css">
script src="../dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```